# How to create a Perl API to pass data back to an angularjs $http request?

Tags: angularjs, perl

I'm using angular 1.5.7 and perl 5.16.2. I don't have the ability to use any external libraries or switch tools - I'm stuck just using what's included with these two.

The angular controller is making calls to a perl file. I'm able to make POST requests successfully, and my GET requests are returning status 200 but aren't showing the data that I am expecting to see. Right now I'm just working with a simple example to try and narrow down where things are going wrong, and I think I just don't know the format to return values from the perl file.

My controller GET method looks like so:

```
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "filename.pl",
        params:{}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.records);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

and the perl code being called in filename.pl is:

```
    my $string = q{{"records":{"2":{"City":"MÃ©xico D.F.","Country":"Mexico","Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados"},"1":{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","Country":"Germany","City":"Berlin"}}}};

     return $string;
```

The string is just a dummy variable to see if passing things back works - it won't be the final data. I have verified it is valid JSON as well. Here's what the response from the server looks like:

```
 {"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"glwizardutils.esp","params":{"FUNCTION":"initcheckboxes","CONTEXTID":"432"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

The data field is totally blank, and the response field doesn't work at all. I can verify it's hitting the perl file - like I said, POST requests work fine and  I included some printouts that verify it's in the correct method, but it's just not returning anything. What should I be doing here instead to get this to work?

Comment: Please show the rest of your Perl code. What you've shown so far isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Check the PERL api from the command line using curl would also try without the special characters in the City to see if there is some sort of problem with the encoding when it attempts to JSON.parse the data out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `filename.pl` is invoked with HTTP, then it should be writing an [HTTP response](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) to standard output. At a minimum:

```
print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n";
print "Content-type: application/json\n";
print "\n";

my $string = q{{"records":{"2":{"City":"MÃ©xico ..."}}}};
print $string;
```

Several frameworks and modules exist in Perl and virtually every other language to handle the repetitive aspects of writing a proper response, which you will want to look into as your Perl server-side script gets more demanding.